# Google Sheets sum mapped text values by group

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to count the groups that have at least one occurrence of specific text values in a column. E.g., if any of `term_01`, `term_02`, or `term_03` are in column B, for 1 or more records associated with a specific value in column A, count 1.

This is not too difficult with a helper column, but I'm trying to do it in one go, with a single formula.

Another way to think about this is that unless every record for a given column A value (e.g. `group_01`) has a value of `term_04` in column B, add 1 to the value displayed in cell `I1`.

Solution with a helper column:
[image]

The helper can be created with an array formula:
[image]

Unfortunately, replacing the `[sum_range]` in `SUMIF()` with an array fails with "Error: Argument must be a range"

Is there a way to pass an array of values to `SUMIF()` instead of a range? Am I going about solving this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I would still be interested to know if there's a general solution to the question asked in the title, but I solved this specific problem with a slightly different approach.

If the number of records with a `term_04` value equals the total number of records for that group, assign 0, otherwise assign 1, and sum the result.

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$10, UNIQUE(D3:D10), $E$3:$E$10, $A$6)=(COUNTIF($D$3:$D$10, UNIQUE(D3:D10))), 0, 1)))`

[image]